# Create cos graphs using matrix-based method on MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I've plotted `cos(x)`, `cos(2x)` and `cos(3x)` on a graph using following:

```
x=linspace(0,4*pi,50); y=cos(x)
plot(x,y)
y2 = cos(2*x)
hold on, plot(x,y2)
y3 = cos(3*x)
hold on, plot(x,y3)
grid on
xlabel (‘x’), ylabel(‘y’)
legend (‘y=cos(x)’, ‘y=cos(2x)’,’y=cos(3x)’)
```

How can I do it a different way using a matrices? If I create a 3 columned matrix representing `cos(x)`, `cos(2x)` and `cos(3x)` by using: `Y=[sin(x) sin(2*x) sin(3*x)]`. What would I do after this? I typed in `plot(x,Y)` but says `Error using plot. Vectors must be the same length.` Perhaps an obvious thing but only recently started using MATLAB. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You're concatenating horizontally using the spaces (i.e., creating one long vector that is three times the length of `x`).  If you concatenate vertically using `;` to create a `3x50` matrix, everything will be fine:

```
x = linspace(0,4*pi,50);
Y = [cos(x);cos(2*x);cos(3*x)];
plot(x,Y);
```